# Asynchronous nature of this.setState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

Let's say that I have these two calls:

```
 this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
    counter: prevState.counter + props.increment
 }));

 this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
    counter: prevState.counter + props.increment + 1
 }));
```

Because setState is asynchronous, how is it guaranteed that the first call to it will execute first?

Comment: Just imagine a queue - first in, first out, regardless of the precise timing of each.

Comment: But this has to do with the Javascript engine, and nothing to do with React itself, right?

Comment: Well, it's React that's implementing the processing of the queue, so it is up to React's code - it would be quite possible to implement something else yourself that accepted items and resolved them asynchronously, in a random order, rather than in FIFO order (but that would be confusing)

Answer (score 5):

From the react [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) of setState() states that

`setState()` **enqueues** changes to the component state and tells React that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the updated state. setState() is also asynchronous, **and multiple calls during the same cycle may be batched together**. For example, if you attempt to increment or add a value to a counter more than once in the same cycle, that will result in the equivalent of:

```
Object.assign(
  previousState,
  {counter: previousState.counter + props.increment},
  {counter: previousState.counter + props.increment + 1},
  ...
)
```

Subsequent calls will override values from previous calls in the same cycle, so the quantity will only be incremented once. If the next state depends on the current state, we recommend using the updater function form, instead:

```
this.setState((state) => {
  return {counter: state.counter + 1};
});
```